# SOAP UI not able to talk to Salesforce whereas browser can

Tags: salesforce, httpclient, soapui

I am not able to connect to https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token form SoapUI (ver 5.2.1). I have tried the PRO version and other older versions (4.6.xx) as well.

I ***can*** access the website from the web-browser. The GET to this URL gives me the response where as SOAPUI says `HttpHostConnectException connection to https://test.salesforce.com/ refused`.

I have checked that there is direct connection available from my PC to this address. I have tried adding `https.proxyHost` and `https.proxyPort` settings in `soapui.vmoptions` and `sopaui.bat` but of no use.

I have also tried playing around with `Preemptive Authentication` settings in SOAPUI without success

My organization has firewall which has white listed this address. I have also confirmed that firewall settings ***does*** allow to connect thru non standard clients (such as ApacheHttpClient).

If I use a Java Program using `URLConnection` using the proxy, it works.

At this point it seems to me that SOAPUI is not honoring the proxy settings.

Please share if anyone has similar experience and how did they resolve it.

Regards
Ash

Comment: getting below response when the mentioned endpoint is hit, which it seems to be valid, tried on SoapUI 4.5.2 : `{
   "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
   "error_description": "grant type not supported"
}`

Comment: If you have a Pro license, you should be able to get help direct from SmartBear? https://www.soapui.org/support/support-overview.html

Comment: @Rao Did you used proxy settings? I think SoapUI does not use Proxy settings while invoking `https`. This URl works correctly outside my organization's network. the only thing which is driving me nuts is that with proxy I am able to get response from a normal java program (with/without) using `httpclient` on my organization's network which certifies that any network related restriction is not there from my organization. Why SoapUI is not able to communicate? It also uses `httpclient` underneath. My be I will post to Soapui guys. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Haven't used any proxy.